# Trying to launch a specific chrome profile for debugging with VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can launch my chrome profile using cmd: `chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 6"`

With launch.json it launches the correct profile:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/account/login?admin_login=true",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "userDataDir": false,
      "runtimeArgs": ["--profile-directory=profile 6"],
      "urlFilter": "http://localhost:4200/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**However**, even with the ngServe running I get this error as soon as the correct chrome profile opens "Unable to attach to browser"

It works fine with the default configuration, but not in the correct profile:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Could the fact that the profile is called "Profile 6" be an issue with the space?

Answer (score 2):

You must quit all running instances of Chrome first, It's not possible to put a running Chrome user profile into debug mode. This is why the extension creates a new user profile by default.